# How to match specific content of a drop down in TOSCA without selecting it?

Tags: tosca

Is there a way to verify that if a drop down contains a specific option without selecting that option in TOSCA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there that is possible. I tried it with a standard HTML combobox. For that you need to scan the page. Select the combobox in question and change the quickfilter to show the items from the drop down. Check the combobox itself and one of the items below (does not matter which one):

[image]

You can ignore the message that the item is not unique - just create the module.

Once you have the module in place, you can rename the item, so that it reflects that you want to use it as a generic item. Then (in the properties tab) add a 'Configuration Parameter' and call it 'ExplicitName' and set it's value to true. This will allow to edit the name of the item in the testcase. ([more details in the help of Tosca 11.1](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=11.1.0&url=tosca_commander/xmodules_properties.htm))

[image]

You can then create a testcase and use the module on it. In the testcase you can change the name of the item to the text of the drop down item you want to check for (you can also use wildcards) and then verify that it exists.

[image]